# Quantum GRE or VLAN?

Tags: openstack, quantum

I am researching OpenStack Quantum with Open vSwitch, and am wondering if someone can answer this question for me:

When should I choose GRE or VLAN for the networking and what pros and cons will i have in using one of them compared to the other?

Answer (score 0):

I have an instance running folsom + quantum with gre. If we talk about pros and cons both are good and reliable, I will share why i used gre.

1. for me it was more handy to use gre as I don't want to configure vlans on my physical switches.
2. VLAN mode has limitations over number of vlans we can use which will increase when you use gre , I don't remember the exact number right now.
3. It is not much impacting the way vm's communicate, it is just encapsulating the traffic before sending it over the link

Comment: But GRE is not very secure right? If i have a Cloud with several customers will they be able to interfere with each other if I use GRE for the networking?